# Mosfet amplifier calculate small signal gain

Tags: mosfet, small-signal

I try to solve problems in textbook. There is an amplifier which is powered by a +Vs and -Vs power supply,

[image: Mosfet amplifier]

The problem asks for small signal gain.

[image: small signal gain]

According to solution manual solution for VIN is like that :

[image: solution manual]

But shouldn't it be like that.

$$
\large V_I=V_T - V_S - \frac {1} {K  R_L} + \frac {\sqrt {4V_S K R_L - 2 V_T K R_L + 1} } {KRL}
$$

Also I wonder whether the small signal equivalent differs when \$ \large v_I = v_O \$ at the bias point.

Citation :

> Agarwal, Anant, Lang, Jeffrey. Foundations of Analog and Digital
>   Electronic Circuits.. [edx].

Note : This is not a part of homework.

Comment: `Note : This is not a part of homework. ` Homework questions are fine on here as long as you show your work. Is \$K\$ supposed to be an arbitrary gain constant?

Comment: The parameter K is related to the physical structure of the MOSFET as follows :  
\$ \large K = K_n \frac {W} {L} \$ In this equation \$ \large W \$ is the MOSFET gate width and \$ \large L \$ is the gate length, \$ \large {K_n} \$ is a constant related to other MOSFET properties such as the thickness of its gate oxide.For example the amount of current provided by the source is given by \$ \large i_{DS} = \frac {K (V_{GS} - V_T)^2} {2} \$